# How does Opus know how many channels are encoded?

Tags: software, stereo, digital

I've looked at the RFC but it's not explicit how channels are encoded. Are channels implicitly associated with frames in a VBR Code 3 packet? I can see a stereo flag in the format but it's not clear to me how this would interact with multiple channels either.

Comment: Some links to the documentation you are referring to might be helpful. Then, how is an opus encoder implemented is off topic here I think..

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure if it's on-topic either, It's probably useful info to sound-techs, on the borderline between format file structure and audio encoding/decoding practices. I'll leave it open for now, see what others think. BTW, looks like the channel count is in the header, not sure what else you want to know.